# Add a Geocoder - How do I do that?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am currently researching for Geocoding Tool vendors and also came across mapbox. I created an account and now I am trying to set up the Geocode with this tutorial webpage:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/local-search-geocoding-api/

It´s going well but as I come to the "add the geocoder" part, I don´t understand it no more.

(the original text from it, that can also be viewed following the link: *The next step is to add a geocoder using the Mapbox GL JS Geocoder plugin. To do this, first you need to add links to the geocoder's JavaScript and CSS to the head of the HTML file.*)

It says that I have to add a geocoder using the Mapbox GL JS Geocoder plugin.
But which Geocoder is meant with that? Is that a different application and where do I get that one from? And how can I add the links to the Geocoder´s Javascript then? And it also says something about CSS and the head of the HTML file. Does that refer to the HTML document where I initialized the map and put the marker in or to the CSS / geocoder?

Can someone give me some advice concering that? I am really looking forward to your answers :)

Greetings,
Tobias Kink

Answer (score 0):

here is the [link to](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder) geocoder plugins github.
You need to create geocoder instance and add it to map as a control, like so.

```
const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl
});
map.addControl(geocoder);
```

Please take a look at the repo for more info.
Mapbox is great, hope you'll get used to it fast, take care.